# Intellisense PCH Warning: Header stop not at file scope. An intellisense PCH file was not generated

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, intellisense

When I open my file on MSVS 2017, I get this error from intellisense:

```
Intellisense PCH Warning: Header stop not at file scope. An intellisense PCH file was not generated
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error, I turned off precompiled headers, and I have `#pragma once` at the beginning. The end of file is at the global scope and not in a macro. I have added the /clr switch to my compilation options. My code:

```
#pragma once

// v0.2

#include<string>

namespace marshal {
    template <typename Out, typename In>
    static Out cast(In val) {
        return In::operator Out(val);
    }

    template<>
    static std::string cast(System::String^ val) {
        using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
        const char* chars =
            (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(val)).ToPointer();
        std::string os = chars;
        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(System::IntPtr((void*)chars));
        return os;
    }

    template<>
    static System::String^ cast(std::string val) {
        return gcnew System::String(val.c_str());
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error at the last bracket. (line 27)

Comment: `System::String^` is not standard `c++` I switched it to `c++-cli`